# I am trying to run npm start and want to run my react app but it's giving me error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

It is giving me this error
saksh@DELL MINGW64

```
$ npm start

sakshee@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpFnx.png)
I have tried to reinstall node js and node modules but nothing is working out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps -

1. Clear NPM cache - `$ npm cache clear --force`
2. Delete node_modules.
3. Delete package-lock.json
4. Make sure you are using one of these Node versions compatible with react18 - `"node": "16.x || 18.x || 19.x || 20.x"`
5. Reinstall NPM packages - `$ npm install`
6. Now try to run your app again, Hopefully it will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update Npm via

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Delete Node Modules

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
```

After that clean cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And then Perform npm Install again